# Add if in Ruby heredocs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to display product details using javascript. I am using haml and RoR-4.2.1. I have the following code

```
var a = new Array();

#{@productlist.map do |prdct|
  <<-EOS
  var t = new Object();
  t.product_id = '#{prdct.product_id}';
  t.name = '#{prdct.name}';     
  t.address = '#{prdct.address}';
  a.push(t)
  EOS
 end.join("\n")}
```

I have a model images which contains the images for the products. A product may or may not have images. So to display images I have added the following

```
t.shop_image =
"#{if prdct.images.present?
          prdct.images.first.image_url
  else
      ''
  }"
```

statements before push statement. But it is generating an issue. How can I add if checking in the heredocs.

Comment: "But it is generating an issue" - __what__ issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**: do the same thing you'd do with "normal" strings.

```
"#{product.images.present? ? product.images.first.image_url : ''}"
```

**Approach 1+**: extract the expression above into a variable, so that your template contains less logic.

**Approach 2**: don't abuse heredocs and [use ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new-label-Example) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I could able solve it by "#{if product.images.present? then product.images.first.image_urll else '' end}". Thank you